# trying to parse csv with a qutoe starting data field that has comma

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to parse a csv that uses commas as the delim 
i have a couple fields that have used the comma in them but have quotes around them heres what i use to try n parse but it seems to skip the if every time even when using test data that starts with the quotes ??

```
          // special case "run,fly,jump"
        tokholder = strsep(&lineholder, ", \n");//gets next token of the line


        //to handle special cases 
        printf("%c",tokholder[0]);
        if (tokholder[0]=='"'){
        char *temp = malloc(sizeof(tokholder)); /// to hold the value of tolk
        strcpy(temp,tokholder);
        tokholder = strsep(&lineholder, ", \n"); // gets next part of quoted comma seperated area
        int lengtht = strlen(tokholder);
        //checks for end quote loops untill it gets end quote in string
        while(tokholder[lengtht-1]!='"'){
        strncat(temp,tokholder,lengtht);
        tokholder = strsep(&lineholder, ", \n");
        }//end while 
        printf("outof special while");
        strcpy(ptrtemp->movie_title, temp);
        free(temp);
        }//end if
```

i am stuck on trying this ?? 
i have to write this in c

Comment: Formatting/indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Some problem could be the use of `sizeof(tokholder)` that yields the size of the pointer not the number of characters in the string. Instead use `strlen ( tokholder)` always add one for terminating `'\0'`. In this case add two to allow adding the comma or quote back to the string along with the terminating `'\0'`. Reallocate the memory to allow memory so the token one can be concatenated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char line[] = "\"run,fly,jump\",walk,sprint,leap";
    char *lineholder = line;
    char *tokholder = NULL;

    tokholder = strsep(&lineholder, ", \n");//gets next token of the line

    if ( tokholder) {
        //to handle special cases
        if ( tokholder[0] == '\"'){
            char *temp = malloc ( strlen ( tokholder) + 2); // +2 for comma and '\0'
            strcpy ( temp, tokholder);
            strcat ( temp, ",");
            //checks for end quote
            if ( ( tokholder = strsep ( &lineholder, "\""))) {
                int len = strlen ( temp) + strlen ( tokholder) + 2;//+2 for " and '\0'
                char *cap = NULL;
                if ( NULL == ( cap = realloc ( temp, len))) {
                    printf ( "problem realloc\n");
                    free ( temp);
                    return 0;
                }
                temp = cap;
                strcat ( temp, tokholder);
                strcat ( temp, "\"");//add the quote back
            }//end while
            if ( temp) {
                printf ( "temp is %s\n", temp);
                free ( temp);
            }
            if ( lineholder) {
                printf ( "lineholder is %s\n", lineholder);
            }
        }//end if
    }//end if
    return 0;
}
```